# Memory size in profiling when i try to detect memory leak

Tags: java, memory, netbeans, profiling, heap-memory

I run java program with `-Xms512m -Xmx1G -Xss1G`. I make profiling to verify the memory, so i `Track every 10 object allocations`. i observe this figure :

[image]

My question is, why it display me that `117mo` represent `40%` while i give `1G` to memory ?

Comment: 40% of allocated memory and i ask netbeans to run the program with 1G memory ? and 170mo is not 40% of 1G !

Comment: 1G is a total memory allocated to java process, i am talking about memory that is allocated for your objects within 1G, which usually smaller amount

Comment: Of course it's within 1G. But When you replay me `40% of allocated memory` ! so What is 100% ?

Comment: it is amount of memory allocated for your objects, if you create only one 1k object in your process, then 1k would be 100%

Comment: It my problem. my `Live profiling result` show me that the greatest object created take `117mo` while in graph of `heap used` it exceed `600mo`.
You can see my question on this morning 
[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13761179/strange-behavior-of-memory-when-i-make-profiling/13761453#comment18916262_13761453)

Comment: i am not familiar with netbeans but i would use heap snapshot instead to analyze heap allocation

Comment: you can recommand me an application to make profiling ? and retreive the heap snapshot ?

Comment: I use JProfiler, but you can also try  YourKit, visualvm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The graph is a percentage of all allocations, not the heap size. Add all the percentages in that screenshot up and they reach ~100%

Comment: If i undertand your response, that when i have for example 50 000 `allocated object` and it takes `170mo` for `40%`. Then `50 000` represent `40%` of all object profiling ?`

Comment: Just that the 117Mo allocated is 40.6% of all allocations being monitored. The number of objects isn't really a factor unless all of your objects take up exactly the same amount of memory.

Comment: So, how deduce the total memory allocated ?

Comment: Find a profiler (or an option within the current one) that will show you the total heap usage, or just add up all of that window.

Comment: when i add up add of that windows it does not exceed `300mo` and when i show the `heap used` it exceed `600mo`.
You can show my question on this morning 
[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13761179/strange-behavior-of-memory-when-i-make-profiling/13761453#comment18916262_13761453)

Comment: I'd imagine that the container itself, the profiler, many other things may be using memory in the same JVM. Perhaps you should try another profiler which may clear things up for you.